# Can I combine this Perl in to a single map-grep chain?

Tags: perl, dictionary, foreach, grep

Can I combine this Perl in to a single map-grep chain?
A little voice says I should be able to, but I don't know how!

```
# expand sponsor keys in to a list of sponsor objects.
foreach my $event (@events) {
  next unless exists $event->{sponsors} && ! ref $event->{sponsors};
  $event->{sponsors} =
    [ map { $lookup{$_} }
        grep { exists $lookup{$_} }
          split( /\s*,\s*/, $event->{sponsors} ) ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of (*readable*) map-grep chains. Despite that, although I know 
map increasingly handles being used in a void context better, I don't like to use 
*map* in a void context. Added to that, I prefer hash slices to grepping something in 
an array. Provided that the value for lookup is not `undef`, grepping all the 
defined values from a hash slice ought to work just as well as `grep`-ing for the 
ones that `exist` and then transforming them into the lookup value.

So I offer this, `map` solution:

```
map { 
    $_->{sponsors}
        = [ grep {; defined } @lookup{ split( /\s*,\s*/, $_->{sponsors} ) } ]
        ;
}
grep { $_->{sponsors} && !ref $_->{sponsors} }  @events
;
```

The problem with using `map` here, is that you're not creating one list of items from another. You are *updating* one list.

As far as my preferences go, you could just as easily do a do-foreach as well:

```
 do { 
    $_->{sponsors}
        = [ grep {; defined } @lookup{ split( /\s*,\s*/, $_->{sponsors} ) } ]
        ;
 }
 foreach { $_->{sponsors} && !ref $_->{sponsors} }  @events
;
```

But that's not that different from your original. And you could just as easily put that foreach on the top. But *then* you have a loop, and I have no problem with the `next` there either. I think the biggest gain that can be made is with the hash slices instead of grepping on and mapping to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think a simple `foreach` would be much more readable than using `map`/`grep`:

```
foreach my $event (@events) {
    next unless exists $event->{sponsors} && ! ref $event->{sponsors};

    my @sponsors;
    foreach my $sponsor ( split /\s*,\s*/, $event->{sponsors} ) {
        push @sponsors, $sponsor if exists $lookup{$sponsor};
    }

    $event->{sponsors} = [ @sponsors ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

haven't tried it, but it should be along the lines of:

```
 my $event;
 push( @{ $event->{sponsors} }, 
         map { $lookup{$_} }
           grep { $lookup{$_} }
             split( /\s*,\s*/, $event->{sponsors} ) 
               grep { $_->{sponsors} && $event = $_ } @events);
```

Comment: Won't work. The code replace the string `$event->{sponsors}` with an reference to an array. You can't simply treat the existing value as an array refernece.